# Properties and Thread Safety

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

As is, in the below code `TextProgress` ends up not equal to `TextMax` due to thread safety. If I place a lock on `_ViewModel` for `_ViewModel.TextProgress++' this will correct this behaviour.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Testing
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ResultsItemViewModel _ViewModel = new ResultsItemViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = _ViewModel;
            _ViewModel.TextMax += 10000;
            _ViewModel.TextMax += 10000;
        }

        private int MAXVAL = 10000;
        private void Method1(
            Action<int> reportProgress = null)
        {
            var progress = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                if (reportProgress != null)
                    reportProgress.Invoke(++progress);
                else
                {
                    _ViewModel.TextProgress++;
                }
            }
        }
        private void Method2(
            Action<int> reportProgress = null)
        {
            var progress = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                if(reportProgress != null)
                    reportProgress.Invoke(++progress);
                else
                {
                    _ViewModel.TextProgress++;
                }
            }
        }
        private async Task TextProcessing()
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(
                Task.Run(() => Method1()),
                Task.Run(() => Method2()));
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _ViewModel.TextProgress = 0;
            await TextProcessing();
            lblResult.Content = _ViewModel.TextProgress + "/" + _ViewModel.TextMax;
        }
    }
    public class ResultsItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        int _textProgress, _textMax;
        public int TextProgress
        {
            get => _textProgress;
            set
            {
                _textProgress = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int TextMax
        {
            get => _textMax;
            set
            {
                _textMax = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This works;

```
lock (_ViewModel)
{
    _ViewModel.TextProgress++;
}
```

However, I have quite a few of these properties that need to be updated in this manner so I would prefer not to have to lock the whole `_ViewModel` but at the same time I would prefer to not create a class for each property. Ideally I could do;

```
lock (_ViewModel.TextProgress)
{
    _ViewModel.TextProgress++;
}
```

But this obviously isn't possible.

Comment: Not sure I understand the last sentence. What would you prefer not to do? In the class `ResultsItemViewModel` you could create a method `IncrementTextProgress` which could call `Interlocked.Increment(ref _textProgress)`, but I am not sure if this is what you are after.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Apologies, corrected the wording and added detail to be clearer. Hopefully this makes sense. I will try the increment idea now.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen So this solution appears to update the value correctly but doesn't trigger my `NotifyPropertyChanged()`. I need this as I have a ProgressBar bound to the `TextProgress` property.

Comment: OK. It would be possible to have a `public static readonly object TextProgressLock = new object();` inside the view-model class that people could `lock` on. Or, with the idea from my first comment, just call `NotifyPropertyChanged` there. As an example: `public void IncrementTextProgress() { Interlocked.Increment(ref _textProgress); NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TextProgress)); }` I gave the `nameof` the true property as the caller member-name.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to make it generic i.e. `IncrementProgress(string propName)`? Then use it like; `{
var temp = "_" + char.ToLower(propName[0]) + propName.Substring(1);
            Interlocked.Increment([HOW TO GET PRIVATE VARIABLE USING temp?]);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propName);
        }`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Guess I could just use a switch but that seems inelegant.

Comment: Not sure if that can be made pretty. Do all the properties have type `int`? It is possible to pass an array entry by `ref`, as in `Interlocked.Increment(ref _backingArrayAllProperties[_indexForTextProgress]);`. The same cannot be done with a backing `Dictionary<,>` or similar. But you could have a never-changing `Dictionary<,>` to map from property name to index number to the array. Or something like `public static readonly IList<string> _names = Array.AsReadOnly(new[] { nameof(TextProgress), nameof(Xxx), ... });`, then `var indexForPropName = _names.IndexOf(propName);` (searches O(n)).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thank you for your help. If you would like to put in a summary of your help as an answer I would be happy to select it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want thread-safety, you will either need to synchronize the access to the shared resource (`TextProgress`) by for example using a lock, or you need to make sure that the shared resource is only accessed from a single thread. There is not much else you can do.

As an alternative to a using a `lock` statement, you may use the [Interlocked.Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx) method to increment the value and store the result as an atomic operation.

But there is no "I do want multiple threads and thread-safety but I don't want to synchronize" option here I am afraid.